# Give ID to submit button

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have a form and i have ended it using,

```
echo $this->Form->end('Login');
```

However, i can't seem to assign it an id or class to style it and be able to reference it with jquery. Also,I want to style it with a picture and the picture has the text already in so i need the buttons value to be empty but i can't manage that either...

Any Help?

Many Thanks, Chris

***Note - this is the html it generates;

```
<div class="submit"><input  type="submit" value="Login"/></div>
```

Ideally i would like to remove the div aswell but its not a necessity.

Comment: Can you *please* edit your titles to remove the redundant tags?  You've done it on just about every question you've asked so far.  We have a pretty decent tagging system here; prefixing your titles with a tag is redundant and doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here's the solution:

```
$options = array
(
    'label' => 'Update',
    'value' => 'Update!',
    'id' => 'blabla',
    'div' => array(
        'class' => 'glass-pill',
    )
);
echo $this->Form->end($options);
```

Cheers! =)

Comment: I forgot: set the 'div' to false to remove the container div...
Happy baking! =)

Comment: Hi, thanks - How come if i put an array directly for the arguments rather than a variable 'options' it doesn't work, while it works for the Form->input(name, array(...

Comment: It makes no difference if you use a variable containing an array or pass the array directly, since arrays are a bit complicated to look at, you may overlooked an error like missing ")" or similar ;-)